# Role of Simulation in Statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

In the field of Statistics, when it comes to "Simulation" - I have usually seen this come up in the following contexts:

- Bayesian Statistics: In Bayesian Statistics, we construct a "Posterior Distribution" for the parameters of interest. We are then required to integrate this Posterior Distribution - however, this integral often does not have a "closed form solution". Therefore, we use different probabilistic based sampling techniques (e.g. MCMC, Metropolis-Hastings, Importance Sampling, Acceptance-Rejection Sampling, Gibbs Sampling, etc.) to simulate random samples from this Posterior Distribution - and analyze these random samples to answer different questions of interest.
- Prior Predictive Checks: To add on the previous point, I have heard that simulation can be used to ensure that the Posterior Distribution is not producing any illogical values. For example, if you are interested in fitting a distribution to some data you collected on the weights of elephants - you would like to ensure that your model believes that "negative weights" are impossible! Through simulation (i.e. "Prior Predictive Checks"), you can ensure that this does not happen.
- Model Robustness and Misspecification: I have heard that sometimes simulation can be used to evaluate properties relating to the "robustness" and "misspecification" of a statistical model. For example, suppose I fit a Longitudinal Regression Model to my data and pick a specific covariance structure - I can then simulate data from a probability distribution having a different covariance structure, and see how well my model performs as I move away from the conditions that my model was created in. Another example - suppose I fit a parametric Survival Model in which I assume that my Survival Times have an Exponential Distribution. I might then simulate data for new patients in which Survival Times follow a Gamma Distribution or a Weibull Distribution, and see how accurately (i.e. robust) my model performs under this deliberate misspecification.

As an example, I was reading the following reference (https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v097i03) in which it states : "*When conducting simulation studies to evaluate the performance of new and existing statistical methods for analyzing survival data, one is required to simulate event times under a known data generating model. Similarly, one may need to simulate event times for the purpose of power calculations when designing new studies.*"

Given this information, I just wanted to clarify the following point: **Are we ever required to simulate data from the same distribution as the model itself? Or does this by definition provide no new information to us?**

As an example, suppose I decide to fit a specific parametric Survival Model (e.g. AFT - Accelerated Failure Time Model) to some data I collected. I read that there a methods that use the "Inverse Probability Transform Method" that can then simulate Survival Times from this same "data-dependent probability distribution function" corresponding to my model. Such methods also exist in the semi-parametric case, where it becomes significantly more difficult to simulate Survival Times from a probability distribution that has not been explicitly defined.

This being said, I am trying to understand why exactly this is important and useful:

- If I simulate Survival Times from the same distribution corresponding to the model I just fit - won't my model be able to handle this data by definition (i.e. "home field advantage")?
- **Why is it important to simulate data from the same distribution as the model** - would it not almost always be more useful to simulate Survival Times from a different distribution and see how well my model adapts (i.e. how close the predictions are) to this new data?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a bit of a tangent, but "you would like to ensure that your model believes that 'negative weights' are impossible" brings to mind the fact that in 2008 the German constitutional court declared the voting system that had been used in federal elections since 1956 unconstitutional because it allowed for the possibility of [negative vote weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_vote_weight). Perhaps they should have run some simulations...

Comment: @ joriki: thank you for your reply! I never knew about this court decision! Thanks!